# Can I use a Maven Profile to deploy a file to the repo?

Tags: maven, maven-3, maven-deploy-plugin, maven-profiles

We have a `devconfig` project that contains files such as `findbugs-global-exclude.xml` among other things.  I want to turn this into a Maven project with profiles to deploy the different parts.  So in my head, the command would be something like this:

`mvn -PdeployFindbugsConfig deploy-findBugs`

...or something along those lines.

My thought is using a Maven `<profile>` in conjunction with a modified `deploy:deploy-file` config should do the trick, but my Maven knowledge isn't very deep in this area.

The hope is our `masterpom` can then have something like this:

```
<reporting>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>findbugs-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <!-- You can override this in your local pom -->                                                                                         
                <excludeFilterFile>
                   <!-- crlf for SO readability -->
                    http://nexus.myco.com/content/repo
                      /r/myco/fb-exclude-filters/0.0.0.1
                      /fb-exclude-filters-0.0.0.1.xml
               </excludeFilterFile>
     </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</reporting>
```

Comment: Is that a config file which should be used by other projects? Furthermore you are going the wrong way...Might be worth to think about a [repository manager](http://maven.apache.org/repository-management.html)

Comment: We're using Nexus. I'm trying to publish our findbugs config to Nexus so it can be used in multiple projects, yet need not be copied to the project.